# Embedded containers in Objective.C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mobile

does iOS have a mobile version of an "iFrame" for native applications that allows you to embed native mobile screens within it? I'm looking to use a container that allows me to embed a mobile screen within a mobile screen of an iOS app. Does this type of functionality exist? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the mobile screen that you want to embed is web based, then you can use a UIWebView.

If, however, it is an iOS App that is written in native objective-c, then you cannot.

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mymobileapp.com]]];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
[webView release];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't embed a native app within another. The best you can do is launch a 3rd party app from another if the other app has a known custom URL scheme.